# Can the paginate method from nestjs-paginate be used with a query builder that returns .getRawMany()?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on application that uses **NestJS** and **TypeORM** with the **nestjs-paginate** library. So far I can only make the `paginate()` method work when the result of the query builder is an `Entity`.

For example:

```
async getUsers(query: PaginateQuery) {

const queryBuilder = this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select([
        'user.id',
        'user.createdAt',
        'user.lastLoginDate',
        'user.email'])

const paginateConfig: PaginateConfig<User> = {
      sortableColumns: ['id', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'],
      defaultSortBy: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
      maxLimit: 100,
    };

return paginate(query, queryBuilder, paginateConfig)
}
```

This will work. The type of `queryBuilder` is `SelectQueryBuilder<User>` where `User` is an entity.

But if I have the following query builder:

```
const qb = this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select('user.id', 'userid')
      .addSelect('user.username')
      .addSelect('user.email')
      .addSelect('COALESCE(SUM(deposit.amount), 0)', 'dep_amount')
      .addSelect('COALESCE(SUM(withdrawal.amount), 0)', 'with_amount')
      .leftJoin('user.deposits', 'deposit')
      .leftJoin('user.withdrawals', 'withdrawal')
      .groupBy('user.id')
      .addGroupBy('user.username')
      .addGroupBy('user.email')
      .getRawMany();
```

then I cannot get the paginate method to work. The query works fine when I don't try to use pagination. Is it possible to use it this way? I can't find any documentation regarding this.